# Почему при сравнении двух пустых массивов компилятор выводит три точки?

Tags: python, сравнение

```
>>> list = []
>>> hello = []
>>> print(list)
[]
>>> print(hello)
[]
>>> if list == hello: print('Они равны')
...
Они равны
>>>
```

Насколько я знаю, три точки значит, что я *создал бесконечный список*. Я не понимаю логики компилятора, либо не понимаю значение трёх точек.
Всё, что я хочу - это чтобы компилятор без "чрезвычайного случая" мне вывел `Они равны` без `...`.

Comment: Ты должен print('Они равны') перенести на следующую строчку с табуляцией. И после ... нажми несколько раз enter)) После троеточия консоль ждет от тебя следующей команды.

Comment: Хм, всё так просто. Чтож, спасибо, что уделили время.

Comment: Троеточием терминал говорит о ожидании продолжения со значимой табуляцией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Три точки означают, что интерпретатор ждёт следующей команды в блоке if. Он же не может знать, сколько всего команд там предполагается, поэтому показывает тремя точками, что следующая строчка будет с отступом. Точно так же будет, если ввести цикл (`for x in range(5):`), определение функции (`def func():`) и т.п. После двоеточия, в общем.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.